# Importxml giving a resource at URL contents exceeds maximum size

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to scrape some baseball data from a site.  I need to projected/confirmed lineups to import into a google sheet.  This was working great until this morning.  Now I'm getting the error Resource at URL contents exceeded the maximum size.

Any assistance as to what this means or a workaround would be a great help.  Below is my code.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://rotogrinders.com/lineups/MLB?site=fanduel","//span[@class='pname']")
```

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately, this won't be possible anymore because the site you trying to scrape has implemented anti-scraping measurements. eg. none of `IMPORT` formulas work.